# Are IDENTITY columns unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

In SQL Server, I have created a Table with an ID column that I have made an IDENTITY COLUMN,

```
EmployeeID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(100,10) PRIMARY KEY
```

It is my understanding, when I use the IDENTITY feature, it auto increments the EmployeeID.  What I don't know/not sure is:

- Is that IDENTITY number created, unique?
- Does SQL search the entire column in the table to confirm the number created does not already exist?
- Can I override that auto increment number manually?
- If I did manually override that number, would the number I enter be checked to make sure it is not a duplicate/existing ID number?

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that IDENTITY number created, unique?

Normally, but not necessarily. Identity column will allow gaps or duplicates once you reseed them.

> Does SQL search the entire column in the table to confirm the number created does not already exist?  \

It need not, what this property does is, just incrementing the old value

> Can I override that auto increment number manually?

Yes, you can. You have to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLENAME ON`

> If I did manually override that number, would the number I enter be checked to make sure it is not a duplicate/existing ID number?

No, that won't be taken care by SQL Server, you will have to ensure you have constraints to take care of this

Below is a simple demo to prove that

```
create table #temp
(
    id int identity(1,1)
)

insert into #temp
default values
go 3

select * from #temp--now id column has 3

set identity_insert  #temp on
insert into #temp (id)
values(4)

set identity_insert  #temp off

select * from #temp--now id column has 4

insert into #temp
default values
go

select * from #temp--now id column has 5,next value from the last highest
```

Comment: It remains unique **as long as you don't fiddle with the identity!** You can easily "reseed" the identity to some start value, and then SQL Server **will** produce duplicates! Just having the `IDENTITY` specification by itself does **NOT** guarantee uniqueness!

Comment: Thanks Marc,I will add that info

Comment: I guess it's important to understand that `IDENTITY` is just **generating new values** from a starting point, making sure - while generating - there are no duplicates. But the `IDENTITY` feature **DOES NOT** check agains the existing values in the table whether those newly generated values are unique or not .

Comment: Two more thing to add - An existing value in an Identity column can't be updated. You can choose to insert a specific value with `set identity insert <tablename> on`, but you can't change a value that was already inserted. The second thing is that after done inserting values when identity insert is set to on, you must set it back to off since you can't have two tables with set indetity insert on at the same time in the same session.

Comment: Having said all that, the identity column in the question will never contain duplicated values since it's also the primary key of the table.

Comment: This is great information, thank you!  Question: If there are already employees in the table, and I add more employees, I am thinking the EmployeeID number will need to be checked for potential duplicates against all the currently existing EmployeeID's outside of SQL, correct?

Comment: no you need to do anything,unless you do some manual insert/reseed.also i dont see the value of incrementing identity by 10 @tddyballgm

Comment: Sorry, I worded that question poorly.  I was thinking if I added employees to the table where the employees had an existing ID already.  Ex. ACME company acquires BETA company and adds the BETA company employees to the ACME company database.  Checking for duplicate EmployeeID's would need to be handled outside SQL, correct?

Comment: Yes,you need to handle that .you can do that outside sql or in sales.In your scenario,you can let sql assign ids to them as well